# EasyBCD can't find Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7, easybcd

I tried to install win7 + ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Inspiron 17R, win7 first ubuntu second using U disk.  At first I installed win7 and ubuntu under ATA and AHCI mode and successfully created entry for ubuntu using EasyBCD, but neither of these two modes can use Intel Rapid Storage Tech (I suffered blue screen when I installed the drive).

Thus I switched to Intel Smart Response Tech mode and re-installed the two systems. However, when I tried to add new entry for ubuntu (add new entry -> Linux/BSD -> Device), the EasyBCD can't find the partition of ubuntu (it can find ubuntu under ATA and ACHI mode). How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest you use grub. Just load Ubuntu on a USB stick and follow this instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. It should detect your Windows partition and create a menu for you.

Comment: EasyBCD is a Windows program, so please ask on a site that supports Windows like [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem but I managed to fix it.This is because Ubuntu uses completely different bootloader. To fix this follow the steps below:

1. start Windows 7. click on the start button and search "command prompt" (without quotations). Right click on command prompt and click run as administrator. a popup will come up. click yes.
2. now type the following in command prompt (without quotation marks) :
   bootrec /fixmbr
   bootrec /fixboot
3. By the way Don't restart Yet! Now open up EasyBCD. Click on "Add Entry" on the left menu bar. Click on the "Linux" tab. On the "Type" section select GRUB2. Now erase where it says "Neosmart Linux" and type "Ubuntu". Last of all select the partition on which you have Ubuntu installed in the last box.
4. Now click add entry. You are all done! By the way make sure windows 7 is your deafult os. Also make sure in the entries menu "skip boot menu" is not selected and count down from 30 is.

Thanks! Please post back if you successfully fixed it or not! If you have any issues please also post back! see ya!